# Payment examples for custom work

Tags: commerce

I have a project where i want to have a monthly subscription model using the payment module from contrib.

I have spent a couple of hours trying to read their docu (both on d.org and the txt file included for developers) but I cannot seem to make sense of this...

Basically I want to create a payment (in code) that issues a payment for a fixed fee, once per month, using the payment method of my preference.

This is what I have so far

```
$payment = new Payment(array(
'context_data' => array( // Add whatever you want in this array, this is passed to the payment method. If your are using Paypal Payment method, these informations are also POSTed to Paypal
  'nid' => '1',
),
'currency_code' => 'EUR',
'description' => t('Product description'),
'finish_callback' => '_mycheckoutmodule_payment_complete', // The function providing the page where the user is redirected after the payment
));

$payment->setLineItem(new PaymentLineItem(array(
  'amount' => 50,
  'name' => t('Product name'),
  'description' => t('Site subscription'),
  'tax_rate' => '0.20',
  'quantity' => 1,
)));
```

$payment->execute();

I want to have a reference (node?) of every payment, or does payment create entities by default after every transaction?

Any help / tips or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Is it just me or is this module very poorly documented?

Thanks in advance!